# Calling function from another function in Bash

Tags: bash

I have the following Bash script:

```
func_1() {
  local arg="$1"
  local var="$(curl $someUrl "$arg")"
  echo "$var"
}

main() {
  # ...
  # some_arg defined
  output="$(func_1 "$some_arg")"

  echo "$output"
}

main
```

However, after running this script, instead of getting the result of `func_1` being assigned to `output` and then printed, the `func_1` is being executed when echoed.

What do I have to modify to execute the function, assign the result and then use the variable in later part of the script?

Comment: Change `output="$(func_1 "$some_arg")"` to `output=$(func_1 "$some_arg")`.  Your quotes are all messed up.  They do not nest.

Comment: @Jack still same issue.

Comment: @Jack, they aren't nested - inside those parens is a whole different subshell. The syntax is valid. Try `echo "$( echo "date;date" )"` vs `echo "$( echo date;date )"`.

Comment: Try `output="$(func_1 "$some_arg" 2>&1)"`. What output is beeing outputted from `func_1`?

Comment: @Forin So how do you know that `func_1` is not being executed?  I put in some `echo` directing output to `/dev/stderr`, and it all executed as written.

Comment: @Jack well, it is executed, but not until the variable `output` is being called.

Comment: That was not the result of my tests.  Provide some output to show that it is not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Clarify your testing with some clear indicators.

```
func_1() {
  local arg="$1"
  local var="$(echo "quoted '$1'")"
  echo "$var"
}

main() {
  local some_arg='this literal'
  output="$(func_1 "$some_arg")"

  echo "[$output]"
}
```

Now if I run it:

```
$: set -x; main; set +x;
+ main
+ local 'some_arg=this literal'
++ func_1 'this literal'
++ local 'arg=this literal'
+++ echo 'quoted '\''this literal'\'''
++ local 'var=quoted '\''this literal'\'''
++ echo 'quoted '\''this literal'\'''
+ output='quoted '\''this literal'\'''
+ echo '[quoted '\''this literal'\'']'
[quoted 'this literal']
+ set +x
```

Seems to be working fine.

Comment: Worked for me, too.  I don't see a problem.